JIRA: Добавление UI кнопки через Scriptrunner
Всем привет!
Суть:
Предположим, на экран создания задачи, нужно добавить UI кнопку, рядом с полем Описание.
При нажатии на эту кнопку в поле Описание добавляются данные с текстом, например test123.
Вопрос:
Как я могу это сделать с помощью Scriptrunner'a?
Захожу в раздел UI Fragments -> Web Panel section, затем выбираю WikiRendererWebPanel, заполняю всю остальную информацию, key нового элемента = test1, и т.д. затем записываю как пример, код из доки adaptavist:
writer.write("""
<div style='
    background-color: #ff0000; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    padding: 10px;  
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
'>
    test1.<br>
    test2.
</div>
""")

Затем когда выбираю нужный проект Jira и нажимаю кнопку "Создать", на экране создания задачи, визуально на странице нет новых элементов. Но если зайти в дерево DOM и выполнить поиск элемента "test1", его найти можно, правда он скрыт за другими где-то в глубине других элементов. Хотя вроде как должен, быть в составе элемента поля Описание, ведь сам плагин его подсвечивает как доступный для использования на экране.
Как мне добавить кнопку пользовательского интерфейса на страницу создания задачи? Может быть, это следует делать через Web Item, а не через Web Panel?
Но в Web Iteme нет элемента id=create-issue-dialog, который создается формируется при запуске экрана создания задачи или я чего-то не понимаю :(
Пожалуйста, помогите, у кого есть опыт владения Jira Scriptrunnerом :)
